# Resize navigation menu area

Tags: html, css

I wan to resize left navigation menu area to make it a little thin. 
I'm using this code example as example:

```css
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  max-width: 160px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

article {
  margin-left: 170px;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <header>
    <h1>City Gallery</h1>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <article>
    <h1>London</h1>
    <p>Lo.........m.</p>
  </article>

  <footer>Copyri....com</footer>

</div>
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_layout_float

How I can get this visual result:

[image]

Comment: Set a `width` or `min-width` on it?

Comment: Where I have to set it? Can you show  a complete answer?

Comment: You want your `nav` to be smaller, so I suggest setting it on your `nav`... just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is reduce the margin-left of "article" and width of "nav"

```css
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  //CHANGE THIS FROM max-width: 160px to the following
  max-width: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

article {
  //CHANGE THIS FROM margin-left: 170px to the following
  margin-left: 100px;
  
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <header>
    <h1>City Gallery</h1>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <article>
    <h1>London</h1>
    <p>Lo.........m.</p>
  </article>

  <footer>Copyri....com</footer>

</div>
```

Comment: `article` doesn't even have a `width` set though.

Comment: margin-left* not width. My bad.

Comment: Can you show me how I can do this with the original code?

Comment: @PeterPenzov, please check the CSS code, I've added 2 comments

Answer (score 0):

Set Margin-left to whatever value you wish like below :
i changed 170 px to 17 px for ex.

```css
article {
    margin-left: 17px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I don't get the desired result. Can you first try it into the editor from the link?

Comment: I tried it there then i posted here. remember to only change the element i said

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `nav` padding to be a bit smaller like `padding: 5px;` and eventually reduce the `font-size` of your nav element so that you can have it thinner

```css
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    max-width: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size:10px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

article {
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <h1>City Gallery</h1>
      </header>
      
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <article>
        <h1>London</h1>
        <p>Lo.........m.</p>
      </article>
      
      <footer>Copyri....com</footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show me how I can edit the original code from the article into the link?

Comment: @PeterPenzov You just have to copy the CSS I wrote, the nav and article tags in particular, and replace your existing CSS (that you gave on your original post).